# Java 8 Stream API Filtering

Tags: java, algorithm, functional-programming, java-8

I have a collection of objects, with the following type:

```
{
    String action_name; //add or delete
    long action_time;
    String action_target;
}
```

Need to get the latest merged operation on each action_target

Sample input data:

```
[add|1001|item1, add|1002|item2, delete|1003|item1, add|1004|item1]
```

Expected result:

```
[add|1002|item2, add|1004|item1]
```

Sample input data:

```
[add|1001|item1, add|1002|item2, delete|1003|item1]
```

Expected result:

```
[add|1002|item2]
```

Sample input data:

```
[delete|1001|item1, add|1002|item2, add|1003|item1]
```

Expected result:

```
[add|1002|item2, add|1003|item1]
```

Is this approachable using Java8 stream APIs? Thanks.

Comment: Please use right format of `Markdown`. See StackOverflow's help documents.

Answer (score 2):

You want to *group by* one criteria (the `action_target`) combined with *reducing* the groups to the *maximum* of their `action_time` values:

```
Map<String,Item> map=items.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(item->item.action_target,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(item->item.action_time)),
            Optional::get)));
```

This returns a `Map<String,Item>` but, of course, you may call [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) on it to get a collection of items.

Beautified with `static import`s, the code looks like:

```
Map<String,Item> map=items.stream().collect(groupingBy(item->item.action_target,
    collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparing(item->item.action_time)), Optional::get)));
```

---

Your additional request of taking care of idempotent `"add"` and follow-up `"delete"` actions can be simplified to “remove items whose last action is `"delete"`” which can be implemented just by doing that after collecting using a mutable map:

```
HashMap<String,Item> map=items.stream().collect(groupingBy(
    item->item.action_target, HashMap::new,
    collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparing(item->item.action_time)), Optional::get)));
map.values().removeIf(item->item.action_name.equals("delete"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps, however, this doesn't help on merging the action part - if input has one add followed by one delete on the same item, output should not include this item at all, instead of showing the latest delete. Adding to this, since the operation is idempotent, the list could be add, add, delete on the same item, result should still filter out this item all together. This is the most tricky part of the problem. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, it can't be solved by simply remove the last delete, e.g. For a specific item, if the action sequence is: del add add add del, we'd still want to include the last del; if it's del add add, show nothing; if it's add add del add, show the last add. Not sure whether that clarifies the problem. Thanks again for your helps.

Comment: The API does not support functions, that are neither associative nor left-to-right evaluable.

Comment: seems like i'd have to sequentially scan through them after group by, thank you anyways for your help